# System.Threading not found

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have got strange problem.

In some of the sources files I have System.threading namespace visible and I can use Thread class.

But in the same project, in some classed I can not use it (no intellisence also).

Here is the using statements for the class where I have no access to this namespace:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;
using CaliburnMicro = Caliburn.Micro;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
```

Any help regarding this strange situation?

Comment: What happens when you add the using statement yourself?

Comment: What platform(s) are you targetting?

Answer (score 2):

Add a

```
using System.Threading;
```

and if that doesn't work, report the *exact* error message(s) here.